# problem loading Mumble-Link Minecraft (Class not found exeption)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have been working for a couple hours setting up a mumble server and fixing up my bukkit server to work with it and after all of the work the mod required will not load in my forge. i've updated to the latest version of forge and re-downloaded the latest version of the mod but to no success

here is the link to the mod :http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272675-1-7-10-mumblelink-forge-smp-lan-mumble-realism

and here is the crash report

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Shall we play a game?

Time: 11/11/14 4:49 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

cpw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: zsawyer.mods.mumblelink.MumbleLinkImpl
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:162)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:502)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:480)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:867)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: zsawyer.mods.mumblelink.MumbleLinkImpl
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ModClassLoader.loadClass(ModClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:492)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: zsawyer/mods/mumblelink/MumbleLinkImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 38 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.6.8
    Java Version: 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Apple Inc.
    Memory: 127753472 bytes (121 MB) / 247980032 bytes (236 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.85.1236 Minecraft Forge 10.13.2.1236 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{7.10.85.1236} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1236.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{10.13.2.1236} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1236.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    MumbleLink{4.1.1-2b3035b} [MumbleLink for Forge] (MumbleLink-1.7.10-4.1.1-2b3035b (1).jar) Unloaded->Errored
    ExtendedPASupport{1.0.0-2b3035b} [ExtendedPASupport for MumbleLink] (MumbleLink-1.7.10-4.1.1-2b3035b (1).jar) Unloaded->Errored
```

Please Help!

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with the Google API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 1):

`Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` indicates that the classes were not compiled for the Java version you are using (in this case 1.6).

The jar you have obtained is only compatible with Java 7 or above.

You will not need this mod on a dedicated server. It is client-side only.

Also note that there are other preferred ways to ask for support. The [Minecraft forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/217587-) and [github](https://github.com/zsawyer/MumbleLink/issues) are monitored by me somewhat regularly.